# Custom UITableViewCell label font problems

Tags: ios, fonts, uitableview

So I've got a custom UITableViewCell created in a nib file in IB, very basic it has got an imageview, and two labels for now.  I've got the table populating with the correct cells in their correct sizes and everything, but there is one slight problem.  For some reason, the font size of the first label is changing from cell to cell.  Sometimes it is the same font size as the second label, sometimes it is the default font size.  This is strange because it preserves the font color and positioning, just the size is wrong.

Anyone know what is going on here?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [self loadCell];
    }
    NSDictionary *event = [eventsArray objectAtIndex:row];
    EventTableCell *eventCell = (EventTableCell*)cell;
    eventCell.mainLabel.text = [event valueForKey:@"Title"];
    eventCell.subLabel.text = [event valueForKey:@"Time"];
    return eventCell;
}
```

the second label always has the correct font size though.

Comment: You'll need to post your code... probably your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method...

Comment: `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [self loadCell];
    }
 
    NSDictionary *event = [eventsArray objectAtIndex:row];
    EventTableCell *eventCell = (EventTableCell*)cell;
    eventCell.mainLabel.text = [event valueForKey:@"Title"];
    eventCell.subLabel.text = [event valueForKey:@"Time"];
 return eventCell;
}`

Comment: where are you setting the size/location/font of the cells?

Comment: i have heightForRowAtIndexPath which defines the height of the cell, but its not the size of the cell thats the problem, its the font formatting thats getting messed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `UILabels` have an option in IB "Adjust to Fit." What this does, is it changes the font size to make your content fit within the allotted size. It may just be a coincidence that it sizes down to the same font size as your second `UILabel`.

Comment: Boy, am I glad that it was such a simple fix.  That did the job.  I didn't even think abou t looking at the text that was being shrunken down